# jtable data getting replaced with previous result when double clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double-click, mouseclick-event

I am developing one application in Swing in which I scan data from some files and show it in JTable on UI and when I double click on row respective file gets opened. Code of 'Scan' button is as follows,

```
JButton btnStart = new JButton("Scan");
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {                         

                File dir = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile(), chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());                
                System.out.println("dir " + dir);
                File[] firstLevelFiles = chooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles();
                if (firstLevelFiles != null && firstLevelFiles.length > 0) {
                    for (File aFile : firstLevelFiles) {
                        if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
                            listDirectory(aFile.getAbsolutePath(), level + 1);
                        } else {                            
                            fileExt=aFile.getName().substring(aFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1);                                                      
                            for (String string : selectedExt) {
                                if(string.equals(fileExt)){ 
                                    fileList.add(aFile);    
                                }                                                       
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                   

                MyFileReader myFileReader=new MyFileReader();

                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){

                        fileMap=myFileReader.fileReader(fileList, filepath);
                       if(!fileMap.isEmpty()){
                         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                             @Override public void run(){

                                    int tableSize=myFileReader.getTableSize();

                                    tableData=new String[tableSize][4];
                                    Iterator it = fileMap.entrySet().iterator();
                                    int j=0;
                                    int k=0;                                        
                                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                                        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();                                         
                                        List<String> ls = (List<String>) pair.getValue();
                                        for (int i = 1; i <= ls.size(); i++) {
                                            if(k==1){
                                                k++;
                                                i--;
                                                continue;
                                            }

                                            tableData[j][1]=pair.getKey().toString();
                                            tableData[j][k]=ls.get(i-1).toString();
                                            k++;
                                            if(k==4){
                                                k=0;
                                                j++;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }                                                                               
                                     model = new DefaultTableModel(tableData, columns)
                                      {
                                        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
                                        {
                                          return false;//This causes all cells to be not editable
                                        }
                                      };

                                    table = new JTable(model);                                                                  
                                    table.setEnabled(true);
                                    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
                                    header.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                                    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                                    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
                                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(5);
                                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(400);
                                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(5);
                                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(5);

                                    pane = new JScrollPane(table);
                                    pane.setBounds(70,250,1000,300);
                                    pane.setVisible(true);
                                    contentPane.add(pane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

                                    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                                         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                                            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                                                int columnChk=table.getSelectedColumn();
                                                if (columnChk == 1) {
                                                    String fpath = getSelectedData(table);

                                                    try {
                                                        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                                                        runtime.exec("explorer " + fpath);

                                                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                        e1.printStackTrace();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                         }
                                      });
                                 scanProg.setText("Scanning Completed");
                           }
                          });
                       }else {
                            scanProg.setText("No codebase found");
                       }
                    }
                    }).start();                                                     
            }


        }
    });
    btnStart.setBounds(324, 154, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnStart);
```

Now, when I rescan files without closing frame new data is getting filled in JTable but once I double click on any row it's data is getting replaced with previous one which is not desired.**I want to clear data from table from privious scan.** Already have tried JTable.removeall() but it didnt helped. 
[Screenshot of table is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOfFR.png)
Any idea?

Comment: Create a new `TableModel`, remove all the old data from the existing `TableModel`, post a runnable example which demonstrates your problem and help remove the guess work

Comment: thanx..I have edited my question again..hope it will help.

Comment: 1. don't add a new JComponets at runtiome, reuse it, (Swing APis - LayoutManager haven't any notifiers about changes, develover must notify that programatically), 2.  don't use null layout, 3. (as Mad mentioned correctly) reuse DefaultTableModel, 4.you have an issue with a EDT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table = new JTable(model);
```

Don't keep creating new components. Instead you can update the data of the existing table by using:

```
table.setModel( model );
```

> .I want to clear data from table from privious scan

Or instead of creating a completely new DefaultTableModel you can use the exiting model.

You clear the data by using:

```
model.setRowCount( 0 );
```

and you add rows of data by using:

```
model.addRow(...);
```